# how to scan line in c program not from file

Tags: c

How to scan total line from user input with c program?

I tried `scanf("%99[^\n]",st)`, but it is not working when I scan something before this scan statment.It worked if this is the first scan statement.

Comment: How about using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead? Or if you're on a POSIX platform [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)?

Answer (score 3):

> How to scan total line from user input with c program?

There are many ways to *read* a line of input, and your usage of the word *scan* suggests you're already focused on the `scanf()` function for the job. This is unfortunate, because, although you can (to some extent) achieve what you want with `scanf()`, it's definitely not the best tool for reading a line.

As already stated in the comments, your `scanf()` format string will *stop* at a newline, so the next `scanf()` will first find that newline and it can't match `[^\n]` (which means anything **except** newline). As a newline is just another whitespace character, adding a blank in front of your conversion will silently *eat it up* ;)

But now for the better solution: Assuming you only want to use standard C functions, there's already one function for *exactly* the job of reading a line: [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html). The following code snippet should explain its usage:

```
char line[1024];
char *str = fgets(line, 1024, stdin); // read from the standard input

if (!str)
{
    // couldn't read input for some reason, handle error here
    exit(1); // <- for example
}

// fgets includes the newline character that ends the line, but if the line
// is longer than 1022 characters, it will stop early here (it will never 
// write more bytes than the second parameter you pass). Often you don't 
// want that newline character, and the following line overwrites it with
// 0 (which is "end of string") **only** if it was there:
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
```

Note that you **might** want to check for the newline character with [`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) instead, so you actually know whether you have the whole line or maybe your input buffer was to small. In the latter case, you might want to call `fgets()` again.

Answer (score 1):

> How to scan total line from user input with c program?

`scanf("%99[^\n]",st)` reads a *line*, almost.

With the C Standard Library a *line* is

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, **each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character**.  Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.  C11dr  §7.21.2 2

`scanf("%99[^\n]",st)` fails to read the end of the line, the `'\n'`.

That is why on the 2nd call, the `'\n'` remains in `stdin` to be read and `scanf("%99[^\n]",st)` will not read it.

There *are* ways to use  `scanf("%99[^\n]",st);`, or a variation of it as a step in reading user input, yet they suffer from 1) Not handling a blank line `"\n"` correctly 2) Missing rare input errors 3) Long line issues and other nuances.

---

The preferred portable solution is to use `fgets()`.  Loop example:

```
#define LINE_MAX_LENGTH 200
char buf[LINE_MAX_LENGTH + 1 + 1];  // +1 for long lines detection, +1 for \0
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  size_t eol = strcspn(buf, "\n");  **
  buf[eol] = '\0';  // trim potential \n
  if (eol >= LINE_MAX_LENGTH) {
    // IMO, user input exceeding a sane generous threshold is a potential hack
    fprintf(stderr, "Line too long\n");
    // TBD : Handle excessive long line
  }

  // Use `buf[[]`
}
```

---

Many platforms support [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)  to read a line.

Short-comings: Non C-standard and allow a hacker to overwhelm system resources with insanely long lines.

---

In C, there is not a *great* solution.  What is best depends on the various coding goals.

---

** I prefer `size_t eol = strcspn(buf, "\n\r");` to read lines in a *nix environment that may end with `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

scanf() should never be used for user input. The best way to get input from the user is with fgets().

Read more: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: `scanf()` should never be used for input strings with spaces, but no problem to input numbers, characters and words (short strings), especially if it is formatted input

Comment: This is so much simplified, it can't be considered correct any more. As much as I appreciate the positive feedback on my document, you should improve your answer, e.g. show an example how to get input with `fgets()`. You're free to use citations when properly attributed.

Comment: Disagree. There is no reason to use scanf() for user input, ever. VolAnd, your response is self-contradictory, as the question is specifically about user input, not verified formatted input.

Comment: @torstenvl the problem with saying "*never*" is that very often, it's possible to construct (maybe exotic) examples proving you wrong. There are notable exceptions like "*never use `gets()`*", of course.

Comment: Felix: I invite you to construct such an example.

Comment: Seldom needed, yet usable cases of `scanf()`: 1) `scanf("%*[^\n]")` to consume remaining non-`'\n'`  after a `fgets()` than did not read a `'\n`'. 2) `scanf("%99[^\n]%n", ...)` as a step in reading input where null characters need to be discovered, something `fgets()` does not do well.  OTOH, with such esoteric `scanf()` use, I find `fgetc()` more clear.

Answer (score -1):

```
char str[1024];
char *alline = fgets(str, 1024, stdin);
scanf("%[^'\n']s",alline);
```

I think the correct solution should be like this. It is worked for me.
Hope it helps.